# Output data from Influxdb to MQTT broker/server

Tags: python, mqtt, iot, influxdb, dataflow

This is my first time working with MQTT and i want to get data from influxdb to Snowflake, but before doing that i must:

- Get data from influxdb to MQTT, which i couldnt find any examples of online.

What i have tried was saving data from mqtt to InfluxDB, using the following script:

```
"""A MQTT to InfluxDB Bridge
This script receives MQTT data and saves those to InfluxDB.
"""

import re
from typing import NamedTuple

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

INFLUXDB_ADDRESS = '10.10.10.247'
INFLUXDB_USER = 'iotuser'
INFLUXDB_PASSWORD = 'iotpassword'
INFLUXDB_DATABASE = 'homeiot_db'

MQTT_ADDRESS = '10.10.10.247'
MQTT_USER = 'iotuser'
MQTT_PASSWORD = 'iotpassword'
MQTT_TOPIC = 'home/+/+'  # [room]/[temperature|humidity|light|status]
MQTT_REGEX = 'home/([^/]+)/([^/]+)'
MQTT_CLIENT_ID = 'MQTTInfluxDBBridge'

influxdb_client = InfluxDBClient(INFLUXDB_ADDRESS, 8086, INFLUXDB_USER, INFLUXDB_PASSWORD, None)


class SensorData(NamedTuple):
    location: str
    measurement: str
    value: float


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    """ The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server."""
    print('Connected with result code ' + str(rc))
    client.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    """The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server."""
    print(msg.topic + ' ' + str(msg.payload))
    sensor_data = _parse_mqtt_message(msg.topic, msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    if sensor_data is not None:
        _send_sensor_data_to_influxdb(sensor_data)


def _parse_mqtt_message(topic, payload):
    match = re.match(MQTT_REGEX, topic)
    if match:
        location = match.group(1)
        measurement = match.group(2)
        if measurement == 'status':
            return None
        return SensorData(location, measurement, float(payload))
    else:
        return None


def _send_sensor_data_to_influxdb(sensor_data):
    json_body = [
        {
            'measurement': sensor_data.measurement,
            'tags': {
                'location': sensor_data.location
            },
            'fields': {
                'value': sensor_data.value
            }
        }
    ]
    print (json_body)
    influxdb_client.write_points(json_body)


def _init_influxdb_database():
    databases = influxdb_client.get_list_database()
    if len(list(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == INFLUXDB_DATABASE, databases))) == 0:
        influxdb_client.create_database(INFLUXDB_DATABASE)
    influxdb_client.switch_database(INFLUXDB_DATABASE)


def main():
    _init_influxdb_database()

    mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(MQTT_CLIENT_ID)
    mqtt_client.username_pw_set(MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWORD)
    mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
    mqtt_client.on_message = on_message

    mqtt_client.connect(MQTT_ADDRESS, 1883)
    mqtt_client.loop_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('MQTT to InfluxDB bridge')
    main()
```

If anyone had done this before or have an idea how to tackle this, i would reaally appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to pipe the data from InfluxDB to Snowflake, you could try to  make best of existing API below:

```
import "sql"
  
data
    |> sql.to(
        driverName: "snowflake",
        dataSourceName: "user:password@account/db/exampleschema?warehouse=wh",
        table: "example_table",
    )
```

See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/write-data/sql/snowflake/).

Well, if you insisting using MQTT, there is an [official and easy way](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/how-to-output-data-from-flux-to-mqtt-natively/) to complete this task via Flux (you could configure these on the InfluxDB 2.0 UI) instead of Python:

```
import "mqtt"
from(bucket: "telegraf")
    |> range(start: -task.every)
    |> filter(fn: (r) =>
        (r._measurement == "cpu"))
    |> filter(fn: (r) =>
        (r._field == "usage_system"))
    |> filter(fn: (r) =>
        (r.cpu == "cpu-total"))
    |> last()
    |> mqtt.to(
        broker: "tcp://davidgs.com:8883",
        topic: "cpu",
        clientid: "cpu-flux",
        valueColumns: ["_value"],
        tagColumns: ["cpu", "host"],
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, but the organization have implied a new architecture where you must go from influxdb to mqtt then kafka and then snowflake.

Comment: updated the answer and hope it could help :)